# How to add checkpoints to Random Forest Model In PySpark Environment?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, random-forest, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I'm using `RandomForest.trainClassifier`.

Supported Parameter are:

- input
- numClasses
- categoricalFeaturesInfo
- numTrees
- featureSubsetStrategy
- impurity
- maxDepth
- maxBins
- seed

But extra parameters like `useNodeIdCache`, `checkpointDir`, and `checkpointInterval` are available in Scala.

How can be these features be implemented in PySpark?

Answer (score 2):

`pyspark.mllib` is in the maintenance mode and is longer developed (access to these features won't be added). If you full featured API use `pyspark.ml` which provides:

- [`setCacheNodeIds`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassifier.setCacheNodeIds)
- [`setCheckpointInterval`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassifier.setCheckpointInterval)